# mysql query works in specific data format only

Tags: mysql

My target is to show the duplicate entries. The first query I have tried is working when my data are like the table #1

the query i used:

```
   select s.id, t.* 
    from users s
    
    join (
        select player1,player2, count(*) as qty
        from users
        group by player1, player2
        having count(*) > 1
    ) t on s.player1 = t.player1 and s.player2 = t.player2
```

table #1 (users) Working

| id | player1 | player2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | p2 |
| 2 | p1 | p2 |

But when my data are like this, the query i have is not working anymore.

table #2 (users) It is returning an empty set

| id | player1 | player2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | p2 |
| 2 | p2 | p1 |

I think it's because the duplicated data is not on the same column anymore that is why it is not working anymore. My target is to have an OR query on the query i used earlier. Or maybe other query I can use? Any suggestions?

In case the table format is not properly formatted, please check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/HMBs9j-i8CjG

Thank you

Comment: It is working ; but produces empty set!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select s.id, t.* 
from users s
join (
    select LEAST(player1, player2) player1,
           GREATEST(player1, player2) player2, 
           count(*) as qty
    from users
    group by 1, 2
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t on (t.player1, t.player2) IN ((s.player1, s.player2), (s.player2, s.player1))
```

Comment: Wow, it works. <3 Thank you so much. Is it okay if you can explain to me this approach? Thank you. I'm willing to learn

Comment: @Dark LEAST/GREATEST normalizes your pair and, if player1 is greater than player2 (lexicographically), these function swaps the values otherwise the values are not reordered. https://dbfiddle.uk/SiEmTIex Of course this possible swap must be taken into account in ON clause.

Comment: Hello, is it okay if i can have a follow up question? 

I have 2 stages, stage 1 and stage 2. 

Is there anyway where i can put a "WHERE stage="stage2" "Only? So it can be specific to stage 2 only because right now it shows even the duplicated data on stage 1. Thank you

Comment: @Dark This additional info needs in a sample. I recommend you to create new topic, provide your structure and data (not as tables like in this question but post a link to the fiddle with tables and data like in my comment, also CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO may be added into the question text). Show desired output for this data. Also you may refer to this topic.